# Qt MainWindow is not updating

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, redraw

I am using Qt to generate a Window. Additionally I use libnfc to get access to a nfc reader, so far so good.
In my self written nfc-class i generate a new thread, this thread is polling for new tags on the reader. If there is a new tag, the thread will start a signal event for the MainWindow.
In the main window I have just a QWebView which will show different websites on different states (after start, new tag, tag removed), just realy basic stuff.

My problem is now: that the main window (or the QWebView) is not updating. If i switch to another programm and go back to my app, the window will be updated. I was already searching with google and trying different stuff but nothing helps.

Here the thread code:

```
class NFC_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    NFC_Thread(NFC_Reader * Reader);
    void run();

signals:
    void NewTarget(nfc_target Target);
    void TargetRemoved(nfc_target Target);

private:
    int mError;
    bool mStopPolling;
};

void NFC_Thread::run()
{
    mError = 0;
    mStopPolling = false;
    while(!mStopPolling)
    {
        nfc_target Target;
        mError = nfc_initiator_poll_target(mReader->GetDevice(), nmModulations, szModulations, mPollNr, mPollPeriod, &Target);
        if(mError > 0)
        {
            cout << "NFC: found target" << endl;
        }
#warning Bug in driver: Timeout generate a NFC_EIO Error, 'https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/issues/detail?id=224'
        else if(mError > 0)
        {
            cout << "NFC: Error" << endl;
            mStopPolling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NFC: no target found" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow Code:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
     void SetNewTarget(nfc_target Target);
     void doTargetRemoved(nfc_target Target);

private:
    bool event(QEvent *event);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
    void adjust();

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebView * mWebView;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mWebView = new QWebView(this);
    mWebView->load(QUrl("http://www.pbuchegger.at/"));
    mWebView->show();
}

void MainWindow::SetNewTarget(nfc_target Target)
{
    QString str = "NEW TARGET: \n";
    {
        char * s;
        str_nfc_target(&s, Target, false);
        str += s;
        delete s;
    }
    //cout << "NFC: Target: " << str << endl;
    mWebView->load(QUrl("http://www.google.at"));
    update();
    repaint();
    mWebView->update();
    qApp->processEvents();
    /*QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(str);
    msgBox.exec();*/
}

void MainWindow::doTargetRemoved(nfc_target Target)
{
    QString str = "TARGET REMOVED: \n";
    {
        char * s;
        str_nfc_target(&s, Target, false);
        str += s;
        delete s;
    }
    //cout << "NFC: Target: " << str << endl;
    mWebView->load(QUrl("http://www.cde.at"));
    update();
    repaint();
    mWebView->update();
    qApp->processEvents();
    /*QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(str);
    msgBox.exec();*/
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        adjust();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    adjust();
}

void MainWindow::adjust()
{
    mWebView->setGeometry(0, 0, ui->centralWidget->geometry().width(), ui->centralWidget->geometry().height());
}
```

main code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<nfc_target>("nfc_target");

    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);

    NFC_Reader Reader;
    nfc_device_string devs;
    size_t nr;
    QString str = "";

    Reader.GetDevices(devs, nr);
    if(nr > 0)
    {
        if(!Reader.InitReader(NULL))
        {
            str += "Error on init!";
        }
        else
        {
            Reader.Start_Polling();
            str += "Started Polling!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        str += "No Device found!";
    }
    w.SetText(str);

    SignalHelper Helper;

    QObject::connect(Reader.GetThread(), SIGNAL(NewTarget(nfc_target)), &Helper, SLOT(doNewTarget(nfc_target)));
    QObject::connect(Reader.GetThread(), SIGNAL(TargetRemoved(nfc_target)), &Helper, SLOT(doTargetRemoved(nfc_target)));
    QObject::connect(&Helper, SIGNAL(NewTarget(nfc_target)), &w, SLOT(SetNewTarget(nfc_target)));
    QObject::connect(&Helper, SIGNAL(TargetRemoved(nfc_target)), &w, SLOT(doTargetRemoved(nfc_target)));

    w.show();
    int ret = a.exec();
    Reader.Abort_Polling();
    return ret;
}
```

As u can see, I have a "Helper" class, this class is just getting the signal in a slot and starting again a signal which will be forward to the mainwindow. If i want to forward the signal directly to the mainwindow, nothing is happening (like the signal is not fired), but i was checking it with the Qt-About box, and the box is showing up.

Helper class:

```
class SignalHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void doNewTarget(nfc_target Target);
    void doTargetRemoved(nfc_target Target);
signals:
    void NewTarget(nfc_target Target);
    void TargetRemoved(nfc_target Target);
};

void SignalHelper::doNewTarget(nfc_target Target)
{
    emit NewTarget(Target);
}

void SignalHelper::doTargetRemoved(nfc_target Target)
{
    emit TargetRemoved(Target);
}
```

no compiler errors or linker errors. this code shows just the important stuff, all the unimportant stuff is removed. just for your information the project file:

```
QT += core gui testlib
QT += webkit

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
 QT +=  widgets
}

TARGET = NFC_GUI
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
 mainwindow.cpp \
 nfc_thread.cpp \
 nfc_reader.cpp \
 signal_helper.cpp

HEADERS += mainwindow.h nfc_thread.h nfc_reader.h signal_helper.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -lnfc
```

Comment: It might be because your MainWindow just drops every event except for the resize event. Instead you should pass it to the parent or base class if you don't want to process it yourself.

Comment: no, i was testing this. a signal-slot is a signal-slot-thing and will not call the event() function.

Comment: Your `bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)` function should `return QMainWindow::event( event );` instead of returning `false` anyway. This is completely unrelated to signals and slots.

Comment: now it is clear for me what you mean! thanks! now it is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer:

Your function

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        adjust();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

eats any event which is handled in `QMainWindow` except for `QEvent::Resize`. You need to call the default behaviour for events you are not interested in:

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        adjust();
        return true;
    }
    // call the parent implementation
    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Note you can also just simply implement [QWidget::resizeEvent](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent):

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    adjust();

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling slots from signals between different threads, you need to make the connect calls with Qt::QueuedConnection as the Connection Type.