# QT - Mainwindow doesn't update unless it's closed

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to update the main window by calling `updateGUI` function in a thread every 500 ms. The window is displayed but not updated with the new values unless I close the window. When I do so, a new window is opened with the new value. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850094/qt-mainwindow-is-not-updating) but it didn't answer my question. I knew that (as stated in qt documentation)

> `QApplication::exec` enters the main event loop and waits until
>   `exit()` is called.

I tried to use `processEvents()` but the main window is opened and closed repeatedly and very fast that I can't even see it. Here is my code:

```
float distanceToObject;
bool objectDetected;
Modes currentMode;

void timerStart(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
        }
    }).detach();
}

int updateGUI(void)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv = NULL;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    // Set text of a label
    w.setDistance(QString::number(distanceToObject));
    // Also update objectDetected and currentMode values
    w.show();
    //a.processEvents();
    return a.exec();
}

void sendMsg(void)
{
    // Send heartbeat signal to another device
}

void receiveMsg(void)
{
    // Read messages from the other device and update the variables
    // These two values change continuously
    objectDetected = true;
    distanceToObject = 5.4;
}

void decide(void)   
{
    // The core function of the program. Takes relatively long time
    // Run a decision-making algorithm which makes decisions based on the values received from the other device. 
    // Update some variables according to the made decisions
    currentMode = Auto;
    // Execute functions according to the made decisions. 
    setMode(currentMode);
}

int main(void)
{
    timerStart(updateGUI, 500);
    timerStart(sendMsg, 1000);
    timerStart(receiveMsg, 10); 
    timerStart(decide, 500);
}
```

How can I update the main window with the variables' values correctly?

Comment: At first glance, your code seems broken in so many ways ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the timer?  Why not just launch the window from main ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
@nh_ I'm a newbie in qt. Could you please point out the most important problems in my code? 
@SPlatten My code mainly runs in threads, each thread does a different function and called in different intervals. In main function, I only call `timerStart` for the different functions. When I launch the window from main, it freezes while the other threads run.

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf It's no problem, everyone is new at some point. But it is rather hard to give any help since your code (besides minor errors) is conceptually doing something different from what you describe in your question. I wrote an answer with some hints.

Comment: This [Getting Started](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html) tutorial may be useful.

Comment: @nh_, I really appreciate your help. Thanks  m7913d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your thread does not update the `MainWindow`, but it does create an entirely new `QApplication` and `MainWindow` on every iteration. Your thread should be stuck inside `QApplication::exec` until you quit the application (e.g. by closing the window). Only then should your thread's loop make further progress.

In general, you must be very careful when doing updates from outside the main thread, since typically GUI operations must be performed inside the main thread.

Think about using `QThread`, which already comes with its own event loop, which you can use to notify/update your window using a respective slot.

Without further details about what you are actually trying to achieve, it is not possible to give you further direction. I, at least, recommend that you create your `QApplication` and `MainWindow` inside the main thread (e.g. `main`). Then it depends what you are trying to 'update'. If you need to progress some data, then you can do that within your second thread and send the results to your `MainWindow` instance using signal-slot. If you need to draw onto the window, then this either has to be done in the main thread directly, or you might find a way to render into a separate buffer (i.e. `QImage`) from within your thread and then send this buffer to the main thread for drawing it into the window.

---

I try to sketch how something like this can be done. Notice, however, that this it neither complete nor compilable, but merely an outline.

First, you have your `MainWindow` and add to it a `signal`, that notifies all observers to start doing their work (will become clear in a moment). Furthermore, you add `slots` that will be invoked whenever one of your values changes. Those `slots` run in the main thread (and are members of the `MainWindow`) and thus can update the window however they need to:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // constructors and stuff

    void startWorking()
    {
        emit startWorkers();   
    }

public slots:
    void onModeChanged(Modes m)
    {
        // update your window with new mode
    }

    void onDistanceChanged(float distance)
    {
        // update your window with new distance
    }

signals:
    void startWorkers();
};
```

Next, you build a `Worker` class, that encapsulates all the 'background work' you like to do (basically what your thread did in your original code):

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // constructors and stuff

public slots:
    void doWork()
    {
        while(!done)
        {
            // do stuff ...
            Modes m = // change mode
            emit modeModified(m);
            // do stuff ...
            float distance = // compute distance
            emit distanceModified(distance);
            // do stuff ...
        }
    }

signals:
    void modeModified(Modes m);
    void distanceModified(float distance);
};
```

Note, that `Worker` must inherit `QObject` and that your `doWork` method must be a `public slot`. Furthermore, you add a `signal` for each of the values you like your `MainWindow` to be informed about. No implementation for them is needed, since it is generated by the Qt MOC (Meta Object Compiler). Whenever one of the respective values changes, simply `emit` the corresponding `signal` and pass the new value.

Lastly, you put everything together:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;

    // create a worker object
    Worker* worker = new Worker;

    // connect signals and slots between worker and main window
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::modeModified, 
        &window, &MainWindow::onModeChanged);
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::distanceModified, 
        &window, &MainWindow::onDistanceChanged);
    QObject::connect(&window, &MainWindow::startWorkers, 
        worker, &Worker::doWork);

    // create a new thread
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    // send worker to work inside this new thread
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    // show window and start doing work    
    window.show();
    window.startWorking();

    // start main loop
    int result = app.exec();    

    // join worker thread and perform cleanup
    return result;
}
```

Alright, let's go through it. First, you create your `QApplication` and `MainWindow` inside your main thread. Next, create an instance of your `Worker` object (could create multiple here). Then you `connect` the signals of the `worker` to the slots of the `window` and vice versa. Once these connections are established, whenever you `emit` a signal, the connected slot is invoked by Qt (and passed values are transmitted). Notice, that this connection works across thread boundaries. Whenever a signal is emitted from a thread different then the receiving object's thread, Qt will send a message, which is processed in the receiving object's thread.

Then you tell Qt that you want your `worker` to live inside another thread using `QObject::moveToThread`. See [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) for a very detailed explanation of how to correctly use `QThread` and objects inside it.

The rest is then simple. `show` your `window` and start processing. Here different ways are possible. I just call the `startWorking` method here, which then `emit`s the `startWorkers` signal, which is connect to the `worker`'s `doWork` method, such that `doWork` will start executing after this signal is received by the other thread.

You then call `QApplication::exec` which runs the main thread's event loop, where all these signals are processed by Qt. Once your application is closed (e.g. by calling `quit` or closing the main window) the `exec` method returns and you are back in `main`. Notice, that you need to correctly close the thread (e.g. by sending an addition signal that stops the `while` loop) and join it. You also should delete all the allocated objects (`worker`, `thread`). I omitted this here for simplicity of the code example.

---

Answering your Question

> I have many functions, e.g., updateClips and mavReceive that should be called periodically and run independently from each other. I should create a different Worker class for each function, as each has different signals, and a QThread object for each of these functions, right? I don't need startTimer() anymore? If yes, how can I control the calling interval for each function (used to be done in startTimer()

from the comment:

The answer greatly depends on what exactly you mean by "should be called periodically". Who is supposed to call them? The user? Or should they just be executed periodically?

So in principle, you can have multiple workers in one thread. However, if they are supposed to do work all the time (spin in a while loop) it does not make sense, since one is running and all others are blocked. In that case you would have one thread for each worker.

If I understand you correctly, you are interested in updating something periodically (e.g. every 500ms). In that case I highly recommend using the `QTimer`. You can set an interval and then start it. The timer will then periodically `emit` the `timeout` signal, which you can connect to whatever function (more precisely `slot`) you want to have executed.

An updated version of the `Worker` could look like this:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker()
    {
        QObject::connect(&modeTimer_, &QTimer::timeout,
            this, &Worker::onModeTimerTimeout);
        QObject::connect(&distanceTimer_, &QTimer::timeout,
            this, &Worker::onDistanceTimerTimeout);

        modeTimer_.start(500); // emit timeout() every 500ms
        distanceTimer_.start(100); // emit timeout() every 100ms
    }

public slots:    
    void onModeTimerTimeout()
    {
        // recompute mode
        Modes m = // ...
        emit modeModified(m);
    }

    void onDistanceTimerTimeout()
    {
        // recompute distance
        float distance = // ...
        emit distanceModified(distance);
    }

signals:
    void modeModified(Modes m);
    void distanceModified(float distance);

private:
    QTimer modeTimer_;
    QTimer distanceTimer_;
};
```

Notice, the connections established in the constructor. Whenever one of the timers times out, the connected `slot` is invoked. This slot then may compute whatever it needs to and afterwards send the result back to the `MainWindow` in the main thread using the same `signal` as before.

So, as you see, you can have multiple timers / re-computations / update signals within one `Worker` (and thus, one thread). However, the crucial point for an implementation is, how long the computations take. If they take very long (e.g. nearly as long as the intervals) then you should think about using multiple threads to speed up the computation (meaning: perform one computation in each thread). As I slowly seem to get a clearer picture of what you want to achieve, I am wondering whether it is only about these periodic updates that you 'misused' the thread for in your question. If this is indeed the case, then you do not need that thread and `Worker` at all. Then simply add the timers to your `MainWindow` and connect their `timeout` signal to the respective `slot` of the `MainWindow` directly.

Comment: Thanks @nh_ for your answer. I updated my question to make what I want to do clear. I really started reading about signal and slot as well as QThread then I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399731/how-to-use-stdthread-with-qts-main-event-loop) which made me think about my current approach.

Comment: Could you direct my which approach fits better to my situation? THANKS

Comment: Added a sketch and some explanations of a way to do something like what you seem to try.

Comment: This is a thorough and useful answer that should get accepted.

Comment: @nh_, I really really appreciate your effort writing this great answer. I now understand how it works. Just have one point that I want to make sure I understood it right. I have many functions, e.g., `updateClips` and `mavReceive` that should be called periodically and run independently from each other. I should create a different `Worker` class for each function, as each has different signals, and a `QThread` object for each of these functions, right?  I don't need `startTimer()` anymore? If yes, how can I control the calling interval for each function (used to be done in `startTimer()`?

Comment: Added another part to my answer, as it was way too long for the comment section.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. @nh_, again, million thanks for being patient teaching me how to do things in the right way. I've update my the code in my question with more details about the project. The functions are just periodically executed and none of them has a `while(true)`. _it is only about these periodic updates that you 'misused' the thread for in your question_ I'm not sure what do you mean but I think this is my case. Therefore, I'm now trying to add the timers to `MainWindow` and connect their `Timeout` signals to the respective `slot`s in `MainWindow`. I'll update you with the results

Comment: What I meant by that is simply that you do not need a separate thread to trigger periodic events (in your main thread).

Comment: @_nh, thanks to your support I got my GUI running as I wanted it to be. I re-constructed threading mechanism in the project by following your constructs. Now it looks much cleaner. Million thanks :)